# How to make a bash script ask the user for a directory and if it's not found, ask again

Tags: linux, bash, shell, git

I'm making a script for pushing files to git. As a failsafe, I'd like to make it so the path to the repository wouldn't be accepted by the script, in case it doesn't exist. 
I'm rather new when it comes to scripting, hence I've come here. I haven't found anything similar or have only seen the same example of use of while and for loops but I'm unsure how to use them in the way I need.
What I've tried:

```
cur='pwd'
    echo -n "Path: "
    read filepath

        if [ -e "$filepath" ]; then
            goodpath=1
        else
            goodpath=0
        if [ $goodpath = "0" ];then
        echo "Please insert a correct path"
        fi
        fi
    fi
    if [ $goodpath = "1" ]; then
    echo "path=$filepath" >> .gitpush
    echo "$Path saved in the following file: $cur/.gitpush"
    echo
    echo
    fi
```

it doesn't even output the "please insert a correct path when I put something random such as /as/asdas/asdsa

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have one too many fi's. Where you have 3 lines with fi in a row, remove one and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
cur='pwd'
echo -n "Path: "
read filepath

    if [ ! -d $filepath ]; then
    echo "Please insert a correct path"
    sleep 1
    $cur/*yourscript*
    fi
echo "path=$filepath" >> .gitpush
echo "$Path saved in the following file: $cur/.gitpush"
```

you could do it like this. so it restarts the script if it's incorrect. That is, of course, if that's in the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

So, a loop, then:

```
filepath=
while true ; do
    read -r -p "Path: " filepath
    if [ -d "$filepath" ] ; then
        break
    fi
    echo "$filepath is not a directory..."
done
do_something_with "$filepath"
```

Though you might want to consider just reading the path from the command line (`$1` etc.) and exiting if the path doesn't exists. That would allow for the user to use the usual command-line editing and history to enter it.

Also, on the first line, `cur='pwd'`, you're setting `cur` to the string `pwd`. If you want the output of the command `pwd`, you need to use backticks: `` cur=`pwd` ``, or better `$(...)`: `cur=$(pwd)`.